# can't use npm at all

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, npm-scripts

so I just downloaded node from the website, node works just perfect but the thing is whenever I try to use `npm` command in terminal it doesn't work and throws this [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8hoY.png)

Also, I tried to update npm but it seems it won't work since I can't use the npm command like `npm i npm@latest -g` and it throws the same [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8hoY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider installing node using [Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm) to install them all over again.

Comment: thanks, i think the problem was node version, but when i tried to google it i was always getting that the "gulp" doesn't work with node and i have to do some cofiguration and stuff